# How to add group secondary x-axis to highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've recently started using highcharts JavaScript library and came across a situation where I'm supposed to add a secondary X-axis in the opposite site to the existing combination chart. I've added the x axis, however I need to group the secondary x-axis as below.

```
Q1 as jan feb mar 
Q2 as april may june
```

Comment: here the link for the reference. https://jsfiddle.net/anandasuresh/n24xoqhn/

Comment: You should add more information to your question. As it is now, it really isn't clear what are you asking about.

Comment: This article will help you to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Moving forward i ll try to give clear example for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions) and [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval) to get desired xAxis

```
  xAxis: [{
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
      ],

    }, { // Top X axis
      linkedTo: 0,
      categories: ['', 'Q1', '', '', 'Q2', '',
        '', 'Q3', '', '', 'Q4', ''
      ],
      tickPositions: [1,4,7,10],
      tickInterval: 4,
      opposite: true,
    }
  ],
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5trabpr/) demo

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable feedback Deep.